# Node npm create-react-app works file "react-app" not created.error occur

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQE8q.png)
Please check my screenshot..

Answer (score 0):

Is there specific reason you installed create-react-app globally? App should get created directly by using `npx create-react-app my-app`